# Stability of cuprous iodide in aqueous solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, reduction-potential

> An aqueous solution of $\ce{Cu+}$ is usually unstable, but $\ce{CuI}$ is stable. Explain. $E^\circ(\ce{Cu^2+/Cu+}) = \pu{0.153 V}$ and $E^\circ(\ce{Cu+/Cu}) = \pu{0.521 V}.$

I found this question while solving a paper and I am confused as to how I should answer. For the first part at least the disproportionation of $\ce{Cu+}$ into $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and $\ce{Cu}$ explains why it is unstable in aqueous solution. (since it is neither oxidised nor reduced by water)
$$\ce{2Cu+ <=> Cu^2+ + Cu}$$
However, for the stability of $\ce{CuI}$ which remains as a precipitate in aqueous solution, I do not understand what reasoning I should provide for its stability in reference to **redox reactions and electrode/formal potentials.**